# asp.net mvc3 how do you format the datetime in the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I try to format the datetime in the view.

```
<span class="tag">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PostDate.ToString("yyyy"))  
</span>
```

here's the error message I got.

Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

how do i fix it?

Comment: This question is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001654/how-to-render-a-datetime-in-a-specific-format-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Comment: to answer my own question:  @item.PostDate.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")

Answer (score 4):

You decorate your view model property with the [`[DisplayFormat]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }
```

and in your view you simply use the Html.DisplayFor method:

```
<span class="tag">
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PostDate)
</span>
```

or you could also use:

```
<span class="tag">
    @item.PostDate.ToString("yyyy")
</span>
```

but if you had this in many places the first approach is preferable because the format will be centralized in a single location.

Answer (score 0):

You can format your DateTime in the following way. It shows full date and time.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:g}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }
```

Then use it into View like this.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PostDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PostDate).ToString().Substring(5,4)`

So you can cut any part of your `DateTime` formatted field.