# Show date part only

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I would like to display only the date on the page.

SQL column has type date.

Model

```
public System.DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
```

View

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndDate.Date)
```

This gives me no warnings or errors, however the time is still displaying on the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DateTime.Date` returns a new instance of `DateTime` with the time component set to midnight (rather than removing the Time completely), it's only useful for normalizing date/time values and is not intended for display purposes.

Anyway, you don't need `DisplayFor`, you can render the date directly:

```
@item.EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: Thank you for the response much appreciated, looks like I still have much to learn!

Answer (score 3):

You can use theDate.[ToShortDateString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx)() or use a [custom date/time string format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

The benefit of ToShortDateString() is that it is CULTURALLY SENSITIVE making your application more accessible.

If you want to use the Html.DisplayFor template helper then you may want to build a ShortDateTime.cshtml display template.  Learn more about that here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6001836/941058

Answer (score 1):

Try the `ToString()` date formatters:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Example:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndDate.Date.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")
```