# How to bind a DateTime in a specific format in ASP.NET MVC 3 using @Html.DisplayFor(.....)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How to render a DateTime in a specific format in ASP.NET MVC 3 using `@Html.DisplayFor(.....)?`
If I have in my model class a property of type `DateTime` how can I render it in a specific format.

```
Data Annotation:
        [DisplayName("Created On")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
        public object CreatedOn { get; set; }
```

**View:**

```
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedOn)
```

it displaying only Date in `mm/dd/yyyy` format, but i want `dd/mm/yyyy hh: mm:ssss` or 
`mm/dd/yyyy hh: mm:ssss` in this format.

Comment: Please refer to this questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001654/how-to-render-a-datetime-in-a-specific-format-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Comment: I tried @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MyDateTime.ToLongDateString()), but it is not working

Comment: See my answer for an alternative solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your requirement just showing date and time in the format of dd/mm/yyyy hh: mm:ssss, no need to use DisplayFor(), use like below it displays date and time

```
 @item.CreatedOn
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DisplayFormat` attribute, see [MSDN Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx)

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", 
                                                  ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime YourDateTime { get; set; }
```

Comment: @PKKG Attribute parameters must be constants.  For an application that handles multiple cultures, the date format string is not constant.  Therefore this method using attributes is not a good solution for multi-cultural applications.

Comment: @PKKG If the format was hard-coded in the model, or if the application was designed only for 'dd/MM/yyyy', then the application is NOT multi-cultural.  My comment of "This isn't a good solution for multi-cultural applications." still stands true for this solution.

Comment: Stop it guys Oliver and PKKG, You both are correct in there respective thinking. Lets have peace

Comment: @PKKG & Satpal All friendly here, just clarifying my point :).  The difference is that in my example, the string can be replaced with a variable containing the date format of the user, whereas this is not possible with attribute parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render the `DateTime` in a SPECIFIC format, you could just render the `DateTime` using `ToString()` and pass the format string that you require:

```
@Model.DateField.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Otherwise, `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DateField)` will use the format defined in the thread's culture.

The thread's culture can be set to automatically use the client's culture (using the `Accept-Language` request header) in the web.config file:

```
  <system.web>
    <globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" />
  </system.web>
```

Comment: It is showing error like ToString() does not have an overloaded method that takes 1 argument

Comment: By the looks of it, you have changed your data type to object, this should be DateTime.  Change it back to DateTime and this error should stop.

Comment: Its not suitable for my requirement

Comment: No change in output whether data type is object or DateTime

Comment: Did you remember to build the solution?

Comment: Hey..If you run the application first it builds the application and then it executes

Comment: It might be worth posting your model and your view.

Comment: I am getting Data from my database in the correct format as I required, but unable to display in view

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ToString() method for your problem.

```
Datevalue.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

or

```
Datevalue.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: It is showing error like ToString() does not have an overloaded method that takes 1 argument

Comment: Then your object does not seem to be a DateTime

Comment: No change in output whether data type is object or DateTime

Comment: please delete `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]` in your annotation and try again.