# Can't convert datetime toshorttimestring

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I got this code in my mvc-project:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Massage45min)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Massage30min)
                </td>


            </tr>
        }
```

Both `modelItem`s are DateTimes. They are now getting displayed like this: `2014-03-23 08:00` and I would like only to display the time. Like this: `08:00`.

I thought this would do the trick:

```
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Massage45min.ToShortTimeString())
```

But it generates this error:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
```

Any ideas of how to display the DateTimes the way I want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001654/how-to-render-a-datetime-in-a-specific-format-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to just print it manually:

```
<td>
    @item.Message45min.ToShortTimeString()
</td>
```

Comment: This answer gives me the result i am after!
Is there any negatives when i use these suggestions instead of the @html.Displayfor?
Thank you both!