# How do I subtract these two dates?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

@Model.Carta.ShippedDate.Value.ToString("HH")  - @Model.Carta.CartaPDate.Value.ToString("HH")
                
How i can subtract these dates?

Comment: How can you *what*?  The verb "rest" makes no sense in this context.

Comment: Be more descriptive

Comment: Are you asking how to format the dates? Because that's answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6001654/215552)...

Comment: No. How i can subtract two dates?

Comment: Start by not converting them to strings :)

Answer (score 1):

Before you convert the dates to strings, you can subtract them which will give you a Timespan (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx)  You can then get total days like this:

```
(@Model.Carta.ShippedDate.Value - @Model.Carta.CartaPDate.Value).TotalDays
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1607352/7875013) is what you are looking for.

Assuming `EndDate` and `StartDate` are a type of `DateTime`:

```
(EndDate - StartDate).TotalDays
```