# @Html.DisplayNameFor substring?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

can I somehow use a substring for this:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Birthday)
```

Currently it displays 06/27/2000 and I want it to display 06/27.

Comment: Did you actually mean `DisplayFor`? `DisplayNameFor` displays the name of the property, it would output "Birthday"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render a DateTime in a specific format in ASP.NET MVC 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001654/how-to-render-a-datetime-in-a-specific-format-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

Comment: Have a look at `DisplayFormat` annotation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.dataformatstring?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Yes Sorry DisplayFor

@schlonzo I tried to use the information in that link but I do not see how to strip out the year.

Comment: @schlonzo OK I figured it out with that link! Thank!